# APNS curl: Error in the HTTP2 framing layer

Tags: ios, swift, curl, apple-push-notifications

I try to send push notification in command line with curl on the APNS production server like this:

```
curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"Test push notifs","sound":"default"}}' --cert cert.pem: -H "apns-topic: BUNDLE_ID" --http2 https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/DEVICE_TOKEN
```

This is the stack trace with the following error:

```
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
```

stack trace:

[image]

Do you have any idea why ?